# code management: generate source files with slight variations of various rules

Tags: makefile, maintainability, code-maintainability

I have a source file in a declarative language (`twolc`, actually) that I need to write many variations on: a normative version and many non-normative versions, each with one or more variations from the norm. For example, say the normative file has three rules:

```
Rule A:
    Do something A-ish

Rule B:
    Do something B-ish

Rule C:
    Do something C-ish
```

Then one variation might have the exact same rules as the norm for `A` and `C`, but a different rule for `B`, which I will call `B-1`:

```
Rule A:
    Do something A-ish

Rule B-1:
    Do something B-ish, but with a flourish

Rule C:
    Do something C-ish
```

Imagine that you have many different subtle variations on many different rules, and you have my situation. The problem I am worried about is code maintainability. If, later on, I decide that `Rule A` needs to be refactored somehow, then I will have 50+ files that need to have the exact same rule edited by hand.

My idea is to have separate files for each rule and concatenate them into variations using `cat`: `cat A.twolc B.twolc C.twolc > norm.twolc`, `cat A.twolc B-1.twolc C.twolc > not-norm.twolc`, etc.

Are there any tools designed to manage this kind of problem? Is there a better approach than the one I have in mind? Does my proposed solution have weaknesses I should watch out for?

Comment: I have tried searching the web, but this seems to be one of those times that not knowing the right terms is a blocker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you added the makefile tag, here is a GNU-make-based (and Gnu make only) solution:

```
# Edit this
RULES       := A B B-1 C
VARIATIONS  := norm not-norm
norm-rules  := A B C
not-norm-rules  := A B-1 C
# Do not edit below this line

VARIATIONSTWOLC := $(patsubst %,%.twolc,$(VARIATIONS))

all: $(VARIATIONSTWOLC)

define GEN_rules
$(1).twolc: $$(patsubst %,%.twolc,$$($(1)-rules))
    cat $$^ > $$@
endef
$(foreach v,$(VARIATIONS),$(eval $(call GEN_rules,$(v))))

clean:
    rm -f $(VARIATIONSTWOLC)
```

`patsubst` is straightforward. The `foreach-eval-call` is a bit more tricky. Long story short: it loops over all variations (`foreach`). For each variation `v`, it expands (`call`) `GEN_rules` by replacing `$(1)` by `$(v)` (the current variation) and `$$` by `$`. Each expansion result is then instantiated (`eval`) as a normal make rule. Example: for `v=norm`, the `GEN_rules` expansion produces:

```
norm.twolc: $(patsubst %,%.twolc,$(norm-rules))
    cat $^ > $@
```

which is in turn expanded as (step-by-step):

step1:

```
norm.twolc: $(patsubst %,%.twolc,A B C)
    cat $^ > $@
```

step2:

```
norm.twolc: A.twolc B.twolc C.twolc
    cat $^ > $@
```

step3:

```
norm.twolc: A.twolc B.twolc C.twolc
    cat A.twolc B.twolc C.twolc > norm.twolc
```

which does what you want: if `norm.twolc` does not exist or if any of `A.twolc`, `B.twolc`, `C.twolc` is more recent than `norm.twolc`, the recipe is executed.