# Make some sub-directories using one rule in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to make some sub directories in a makefile. I know how to do it using a rule for each sub-directory. I am looking for the syntax that will do it using one rule for all subdirectories (either using a loop or using SUBDIRs list).

For example:

```
$(dst_dir)/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/rm/src/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@)

$(dst_dir)/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/utility/src/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@)

$(dst_dir)/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/fota/src/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@)

$(dst_dir)/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/fota/src/lzo/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@)
```

Comment: The heavy repetition makes it harder to see what you are trying to accomplish, and is an antipattern in its own right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: Are you simply looking for `mkdir -p "$(dst_dir)"`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job (GNU make):

```
define DIR_RULE
$$(dst_dir)/%.o : $$(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/$(1)/%.c
    $$(TRACE_CC)
    $$(Q)$$(GCC) -c $$(CFLAGS) $$< -o $$@
    $$(Q)$$(GCC) -c $$(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $$@ -MF $$(subst .o,.d,$$@) $$< -o $$(subst .o,.d,$$@)
endef
SUBDIRS = rm/src utility/src fota/src fota/src/lzo
$(foreach d,$(SUBDIRS),$(eval $(call DIR_RULE,$(d))))
```

For a slightly more detailed explanation, see for instance this [other question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669257/code-management-generate-source-files-with-slight-variations-of-various-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think what you're looking for is this:

```
#-------------------------------------
define mk_subdir =

$1/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/rm/src/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@)

$1/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/utility/src/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@)

$1/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/fota/src/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@)

$1/%.o : $(M2M_GENERIC_DIR)/fota/src/lzo/%.c
    $(TRACE_CC)
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(Q)$(GCC) -c $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(subst .o,.d,$@) $< -o $(subst .o,.d,$@) 

endef
#-------------------------------------

foreach (dir,$(SUBDIRS),$(eval $(call mk_subdir,$(dir)))
```

See [eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) for more details.

Of course defines like these make it hard for others to understand/debug/maintain makefiles, so only use if you really need to...   (disclaimer -- I never tested the above code, so there could be a syntax error hiding in there somewhere...)